# Can $e^{t(X+Y)}=e^{tX}O_t$ be solved for $O_t$, when the operators $X$ and $Y$ don't commute?

Tags: functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

What is the exact solution $O_t$ of $e^{t(X+Y)}=e^{tX}O_t$, when $X$ and $Y$ are non-commuting operators on a Hilbert space? All I found is the [Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula), but it gives the solution $Z$ of $e^Xe^Y=e^Z$.

Comment: Why isn't exponential defined?  You obviously have at least the series $\exp(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n!$ defined on $\bigcap_n\operatorname{dom}(x^n)$ and you can take the maximal symmetric extension for $\exp D^2$.

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you very much for having a look at the other question! The problem is that the domain of $D$ is not a Banach space (not even an inner product space, I'm afraid all we have is a bilinear map), so I'm not sure how the formula $\exp(X)\psi=\sum_{n=0}^\infty X^n\psi/n!$ or $\exp(X)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty X^n/n!$  (where $X=D^2$) would have to be understood. (Maybe one idea would be to consider equivalence classes, like in the case of square integrable functions...)

Comment: The usual approach is: take the space of $C^\infty_c$ spinors, complete it (say) to $L^2$-spinors and consider Sobolev-type embedding (hence $\bigcap_k L^2_k\subset C^\infty$) with $D$ a $\psi$DO $L^2_k(S\otimes E)\to L^2_{k-1}(S\otimes E)$.